# Parsing JSON data in Golang

Tags: json, go

In Go, I make an API call and receive back a []byte full of data. When I print out the array using `string(res)`, I can see the raw JSON Object. It looks like this:

`{"success": true, "data": [{"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": 300},{"a": 200, "b": 400, "c": 600}]}`

I also have created a struct that looks like this

```
type SomethingCool struct {
  A int `json:"a"`
  B int `json:"b"`
  C int `json:"c"`
}
```

In the response from the API, I only care about the information contained within the `data` object. What I want to do is loop over the items in `data`, and create a new `SomethingCool` of each object. Finally, I want to return an array of all structs that were created from looping through `data`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are countless examples of parsing JSON in Go available on the web, and dozens if not hundreds of questions with information about it here on SO.

Comment: I have, but have yet to find something on how to parse an array of objeccts contained within an json object. Most examples provide only a basic example of parsing a simple object.

Comment: See https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the `data` field of the JSON, you need to create a similar struct and decode the JSON payload into it.

```golang
var incomingJSON struct {
    Data []SomethingCool `json:"data"`
}
```

When you unmarshall the JSON into this struct, you should have access to your data as a slice of `SomethingCool`s.

Full program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type SomethingCool struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
    B int `json:"b"`
    C int `json:"c"`
}

func main() {
    var response = []byte(`{"success": true, "data": [{"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": 300},{"a": 200, "b": 400, "c": 600}]}`)
    var incomingJSON struct {
        Data []SomethingCool `json:"data"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(response, &incomingJSON); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Data: ", incomingJSON)
    }
}
```